# printing byte chars in C

Tags: c, string, byte

i have an input c-string that seems to be in bytes or octets.
when i print it by doing

```
printf("this is string[%s]\n", inputCstr);
```

it doesn't print the whole thing.
so i tried to loop it like

```
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    printf("inputCstr[%d] = %c", i, inputCstr[i]);
}
```

this loops through entire string but this actually skips some indices. for example, if the string was "abcdefg", it will give
something like

```
inputCstr[0] = a
inputCstr[2] = c
inputCstr[5] = f
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Sounds like a Unicode issue to me, just off hand. What is the type of inputCStr?

Comment: How are you examining the output of the program? Consider what you would see if item #1,3 and 4 were `'\r'`. Try printing the integer values rather than the character values: `printf("inputCstr[%d] = %x", i, inputCstr[i]);`

Comment: What is the type of inputCstr ?

Comment: I think a short main program that has the problem will be best to help you

Answer (score 5):

That's because there are control characters in the byte array that are interpreted specially by your console.

In your case you may have encountered, for example `\r` or something like that, that moves the cursor to the 1st column and the next line overwrite the previous one.

You can try:

```
for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
    printf("inputCstr[%d] = %02X\n", i, (unsigned char)inputCstr[i]);
}
```

And see the real codes.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. how do i detect something like \r in the string? i tried your code and it prints out values but index is still skipping.

Comment: I find hard to believe that this code skips indices... Try adding a '\n' at the end of the format string (I've just edited the answer), just in case some of the text goes out to the right of the screen.

Comment: inputCstr[4198] = 6F
 inputCstr[4201] = 64
 inputCstr[4205] = 6C
 inputCstr[4268] = 6F

Comment: sorry. not sure how to format comments nicely. but as you can see above, it skips index.

Answer (score 4):

From Wikipedia ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string ):

> In computer programming, a null-terminated string is a character
>   string stored as an array containing the characters and terminated
>   with a null character ('\0', called NUL in ASCII). Alternative names
>   are C string, which refers to the C programming language and ASCIIZ
>   (note that C strings do not imply the use of ASCII).
>
> The length of a C string is found by searching for the (first) NUL
>   byte

In your case I would have to say that you are probably using a wide-char string (unicode) which uses 2 bytes for every character. This is why you only see the first character when printing the string (because the second byte is '\0').

In order to print the string correctly you have to choose :

1. Change the string from wide-char to char (wchar to char)
2. Use wprintf instead of printf in order to print wide-char strings

Good luck,

Tal.